# Increment a variable inside ng-class directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got this code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="validation() ? 'active-'+getCounter()' : 'not-active'">
    <a ng-click="activate()">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="validation() ? 'active-'+getCounter()' : 'not-active'">
    <a ng-click="activate()">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make a script in angular that when you click on the link there is a variable that increase so that the parent `<li>` get a class active-(incrementing variable).
The problem is that when I click on a link, and the variable get increased, it updates the class for all the `<li>`.

Example: I click on first link it gives me `active-1` as class then i click on a second link it gives me `active-2` but first li get `active-2` as well and i want it stays `active-1`

I hope you can help me doing this script.

Link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWlryR0xKXFoQ3ZweW2H?p=preview)

Comment: the activate function increments the var increment by 1, while the getCounter function just returns the increment variable.

Comment: can you put your code to http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Here http://plnkr.co/edit/GWlryR0xKXFoQ3ZweW2H?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I try with another interpretation of your question:

You want:

- the ability to activate your `<li>s` separately, and provide a class active-1 for `<li>`one active-2 for `<li>` two...
- when clicking an `<li>` it should be activated and given the proper class

so I made some modifications to the Plunker from my previous answer, and you can find the new Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/a5ZNc1OKUrTpYTb4fIRi?p=preview).

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul>
  <li ng-class=" validation(0) ? 'active-'+getCounter(0) : 'not-active'">
    <a href='' ng-click="activate(0)">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class=" validation(1) ? 'active-'+getCounter(1) : 'not-active'">
    <a href='' ng-click="activate(1)">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
(function($){

    var app = angular.module('test',[]);

    app
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        // Variable not in scope
        var counterClick = [1,2];

        $scope.validationNum = [];

        $scope.activate = function(id) {
            $scope.validationNum.push(id);
            console.log(counterClick)
        }

        $scope.getCounter = function(id) {
            return counterClick[id];
        }

        $scope.validation = function(id) {
            if ($.inArray(id, $scope.validationNum) > -1)
                return true;
        }
    }]);


})(jQuery);
```

style.css:

```
/* Styles go here */

.not-active{
  background-color: red;
}
.active-1{
  background-color: #fff;
}
.active-2{
  background-color: blue;
}

.active-3{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your `<li>s` individually you need to have different counters for them. In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TT2qoy6cRFagZxMfTRJU?p=preview) I've modified the `var counterClick` to be an array, and updated your html to use id 0 and 1 for `<li>` number 1 and 2.

index.html becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul>
  <li ng-class=" validation(0) ? 'active-'+getCounter(0) : 'not-active'">
    <a href='' ng-click="activate(0)">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class=" validation(1) ? 'active-'+getCounter(1) : 'not-active'">
    <a href='' ng-click="activate(1)">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js becomes:

```
(function($){

    var app = angular.module('test',[]);

    app
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        // Variable not in scope
        var counterClick = [0,0];

        $scope.validationNum = [];

        $scope.activate = function(id) {
            counterClick[id] += 1;
            $scope.validationNum.push(id);
            console.log(counterClick)
        }

        $scope.getCounter = function(id) {
            return counterClick[id];
        }

        $scope.validation = function(id) {
            if ($.inArray(id, $scope.validationNum) > -1)
                return true;
        }
    }]);


})(jQuery);
```

I've also added some basic classes to the style.css

```
.not-active{
  background-color: red;
}
.active-1{
  background-color: #fff;
}
.active-2{
  background-color: blue;
}

.active-3{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working as i was expecting.. Clicking on the first link it adds active-1, clicking on the second link it adds active-1, but it should be active-2 :S thanks anyway

Comment: In which way does it not live up to your expectations? Perhaps you could clarify you question so that there's no room for misinterpretation?